# Error deploying in vercel (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and'))

Tags: javascript, next.js, build, vercel, gsap

I met this error while deploying on vercel. Npm run build showed no error

Config :
"node": "18",
"next": "^14.0.0",
"next-transpile-modules": "^9.1.0",

```
Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')
    at Object.webpack (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next-transpile-modules/src/next-transpile-modules.js:206:60)
    at getBaseWebpackConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js:1713:32)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
    at async webpackBuildImpl (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-build/impl.js:132:21)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:694:115
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
    at async build (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:186:29)
    at async main (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:150:5)
```

I don't understand where it's coming from, because everything was fine before

Here is my next.config.js :
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["gsap"])

module.exports = withTM({

```
  images: {
    domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
    loader: "cloudinary",
    path: "https://res.cloudinary.com/",
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "fr"],
    defaultLocale: "fr",
  },
})
```

The part concerned in the error :

if (nextCssLoader) {
nextCssLoader.issuer.or = nextCssLoader.issuer.and ? nextCssLoader.issuer.and.concat(matcher) : matcher;
delete nextCssLoader.issuer.not;
delete nextCssLoader.issuer.and;
} else {
console.warn('next-transpile-modules - could not find default CSS rule, CSS imports may not work');
}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just update next-transpile-modules to the version 10 and it worked